# Dynamically calculate height of custom TableView Cell programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, height

I have the below code to define my custom tableView cell Class:

```
import UIKit

import ChameleonFramework

class IsectionsCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionDesignationLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionDesignationLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let depthOfSectionLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 5

    let depthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let depthOfSectionLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 2.50

    let webThicknessLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 5

    let webThicknessLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 2.50

    let webThicknessLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let widthOfSectionLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 5

    let widthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let widthOfSectionLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 2.50

    let sectionFlangeThicknessLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 5

    let sectionFlangeThicknessLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 2.5

    let sectionFlangeThicknessLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionMassPerMetreLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 5

    let sectionMassPerMetreLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionMassPerMetreLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 2.5

    var tableCellContainer: UIView = {

        let container = UIView()

        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        container.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatPink()

        return container

    }()

    var sectionDesignationLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        return label

    }()

    var depthOfSectionLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        return label

    }()

    var widthOfSectionLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        return label

    }()

    var sectionWebThicknessLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        return label

    }()

    var sectionFlangeThicknessLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return label

    }()

    var sectionMassPerMetreLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        label.numberOfLines = 0

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return label

    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(tableCellContainer)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(sectionDesignationLabel)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(depthOfSectionLabel)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(sectionWebThicknessLabel)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(widthOfSectionLabel)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(sectionFlangeThicknessLabel)

        tableCellContainer.addSubview(sectionMassPerMetreLabel)

        applyAppropriateSizeAndConstraintsForCellItems()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }

    func applyAppropriateSizeAndConstraintsForCellItems() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            tableCellContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),

            tableCellContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),

            tableCellContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),

            tableCellContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),

            sectionDesignationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.topAnchor, constant: sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding),

            sectionDesignationLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.leftAnchor, constant: sectionDesignationLabelLeftPadding),

            sectionDesignationLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -1*sectionDesignationLabelRightPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionDesignationLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: depthOfSectionLabelTopPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.leftAnchor, constant: depthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: -1*depthOfSectionLabelRightPadding),

            sectionWebThicknessLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionDesignationLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: webThicknessLabelTopPadding),

            sectionWebThicknessLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: webThicknessLabelLeftPadding),

            sectionWebThicknessLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -1*webThicknessLabelRightPadding),

            widthOfSectionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: depthOfSectionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: widthOfSectionLabelTopPadding),

            widthOfSectionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.leftAnchor, constant: widthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding),

            widthOfSectionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: -1*widthOfSectionLabelRightPadding),

            sectionFlangeThicknessLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionWebThicknessLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: sectionFlangeThicknessLabelTopPadding),

            sectionFlangeThicknessLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: sectionFlangeThicknessLabelLeftPadding),

            sectionFlangeThicknessLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -1*sectionFlangeThicknessLabelRightPadding),

            sectionMassPerMetreLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthOfSectionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: sectionMassPerMetreLabelTopPadding),

            sectionMassPerMetreLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.leftAnchor, constant: sectionMassPerMetreLabelLeftPadding),

            sectionMassPerMetreLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableCellContainer.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: -1*sectionMassPerMetreLabelRightPadding)

            ])

    }

}
```

The above works well when I specify a height for all cells greater than 150 (refer to attached image). [image]

However, what I would like to achieve is for the tableCellContainer UIView defined in the code inside the custom TableViewCell Class to be able to calculate its height based on the subviews inside it. Thus, I based on the attached image, I would like to be able to calculate the height of the sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding + + sectionDesignationLabelHeight + depthOfSectionLabelTopPadding + depthOfSectionLabelHeight + widthOfSectionLabelTopPadding + widthOfSectionLabelHeight + massPerMetreLabelTopPadding + massPerMetreLabelHeight. And then compare the total against the total of sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding + sectionDesignationLabelHeight + webThicknessLabelTopPadding + webThicknessLabelHeight + flangeThicknessLabelTopPadding + flangeThicknessLabelHeight. And I would like the maximum total between the two to be set as the height of the tableCellContainer UIView.

What I tried to do is as follow:

Inside the ViewController which contains the tableView, specifically inside the cellForRowAt indexPath function, to calculate the height of each label and then set the maximum total as the height of the container. However, this did not work, as it returned the wrong values for the height of each UILabel item.

Could someone please guide me on the best place and method on how can I achieve what I am looking for, thanks a lot in advanced?

Regards,
Shadi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, That is EPIC size code to share. You should always start with much smaller code to test new things you want to learn.

Second of all, the ability you are looking for is called **Self sizing tableView cell**. There are plenty of tutorials out there to help you reach that.

But I explain to you shortly:

- First, all subviews should either have capability of self-sizing (like `UILabel` and `UIButton` or you own custom classes) or have exact height size with `constraint`s.
- Then all of them should have relation to the `contentView` of the cell (or the cell itself) somehow. Like this:  `V: contentViewTop-subview1-subview2-subview3-contentViewBottom`
- Then if you set the `tableView.rowHeight` to `UITableView.automaticDimension`, it will automatically get the intrinsic content size of all subviews and apply it to the cell height.

This tutorial can help you better understanding with more details:

[Self-sizing-table-view-cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tutorial you shared, it solved my issue. I was not aware of the fact that AutomaticHeight only works when you specify all four AutoLayout Constraints, thanks again.